# Docker "protocol not available" after context change

Tags: docker

I changed my docker context. Now when I run any docker command, I get `protocol not available`. How do I change my context back if I can't run any docker commands?

Basically I did the following.

1. I ran `docker context list`. I saw 2 contexts available (`default`, which was active, with the description 'Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration'; and `desktop-linux` with no description and an endpoint  piped to dockerDesktopLinuxEngine.)
2. I changed my docker context: `docker context use desktop-linux`
3. Now I can't do any docker commands, including changing my context back.

I'm running Docker Desktop on Windows using the WSL2 backend (Debian 10). Kubernetes is enabled and kubectl still functions as expected.

How do I fix my docker install so that I can run commands again?

I've tried:

- restarting the WSL
- restarting Docker Desktop
- 'factory reset' of Docker Desktop

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In the file `~/.docker/config.json` there will be a `"currentContext": "some-name"` line. You can delete this line to return to the default context. If that's the last line, make sure to delete the comma on the previous line to keep the json valid.

Comment: Good answer for linux, but, what about windows? Do you know something about it without reinstalling Docker-Desktop? Thx

Comment: This _is_ the answer for Windows; the "linux" bits are in the WSL2 backend. There was no DD reinstall necessary. @AlejandroGalera

Comment: I'm encountering the same 'protocol not available' issue, but it doesn't seem to be related to the context change. Any assistance with resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For me I had configure ~/.docker/config.json with only

```
{
  "credsStore": "desktop.exe"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same "Protocol not available" error, but it wasn't related to context: I'm on an M1 Macbook and I had to enable "Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon" under "Features in development" for the error to go away.

I know the question explicitly mentions a context change, but I thought I'd share my unrelated scenario in case it helps anyone else.